# Options for using MSVC static libraries with MinGW (reimp was unable to convert them)

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, sdk, mingw, static-libraries

I work for a company that recently purchased a piece of hardware accompanied by an SDK. Unfortunately, all the SDK libraries were compiled with a Microsoft Visual C++ compiler (I don't know which one) and cannot be used by [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) (I develop in Code::Blocks using the MinGW C++ compiler).

I've attempted to convert the libraries using reimp (from the [MinGW utilities collection](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Extension/mingw-utils/)), which has worked in the past with static libraries from other vendors, but in this case the converted libraries result in "undefined reference" errors when linked.

The def files generated by reimp for each library during the conversion process don't look very good (they're filled with lines like `??0nameOfFunction@@QEAA@AEBV0@@Z`, while the def files generated during a successful conversion contain lines similar to `nameOfFunction@32`), so it seems that the vendor's libraries are simply of a type that reimp can't convert.

Are there any other options that would allow me to use these libraries with MinGW? If not, is it reasonable to request that the vendor recompile their libraries with g++ (i.e., is it something they could feasibly do given that the libraries were originally developed using MSVC)?

Any comments or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: If these are C++ libraries, then, I'm afraid, you are out of luck.

Comment: @Haroogan, out of luck on both fronts? (Using the existing libraries with MinGW or getting the vendor to rebuild them?)

Comment: Of course if vendor rebuilds them, then it's allright.

Comment: If the vendor agrees to rebuild them, any thoughts on whether they'll need to do so using g++ or if there's a way they could still use MSVC (which I imagine would be easier for them) but produce a library that reimp could successfully convert?

Comment: No they have to do it with `g++` and they have no choice in this regard as long as this is C++. If that was pure C API, then it would be as simple as running `reimp` or `gendef`.

Comment: I also encounter such kind of problem, I use lib2a to covert it. Successfully linked but spurious running result :(